# DOM ready in Dartium

Tags: dart

Calling focus() inside main() doesn't stick when Dartium is first run (OS X via Dart Editor). There is something async going on that changes focus to the URL bar. Works if Dartium already running. Is there some event I can hook to reliably set focus? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some code so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: Built trivial reproducer. Filed bug [12283](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12283)

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Does it work for you if you do `runAsync(() => query("#text").focus());`? (requires dart:async)

Comment: Nope. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments in [Issue 12283](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12283), seems like this would require changes in Chrome to fix. It's not clear if it's a bug, or missing feature, but I think the chances of it being addressed are probably slim :-/